# Can't install Java Runtime

Tags: software-installation, java, wine

I have problems with installing Java Runtime on Wine.
When I run the setup file it takes five seconds
and reports that a serious error has been detected.
What to do? I need it to run Minecraft.

Wine version is 1.8. 
(Maybe my version is too old to be able to install Java Runtime on it?)

Answer (score 0):

To run Minecraft you do not need to use wine. Install jdk, then install/update video drivers and install Minecraft itself. Check the [manual here](https://www.howtogeek.com/198476/how-to-install-minecraft-on-ubuntu-or-any-other-linux-distribution/) (quoted text is from there)

> How to Install Minecraft on Ubuntu or Any Other Linux Distribution by
>   Chris Hoffman on October 16th, 2014
>   install-minecraft-on-ubuntu-or-another-linux-distribution
>
> Minecraft runs just fine on Linux, but it’s probably not available for
>   easy installation in your Linux distribution’s package manager. Here’s
>   how to get your Linux system ready for Minecraft.
>
> We used Ubuntu 14.04 for this process, and that’s where our concrete
>   examples come from. But the process will be almost the same on every
>   Linux distribution.
>
> Install Proprietary Graphics Drivers
>
> Minecraft is a 3D application, so it benefits from having good 3D
>   drivers installed. If you have Intel graphics, you’re good to go —
>   Intel graphics aren’t as powerful as NVIDIA or AMD graphics, but they
>   do work well with the standard open-source graphics drivers provided
>   by your Linux distribution.
>
> If you have NVIDIA or AMD graphics, you should probably install the
>   closed-source NVIDIA or AMD graphics drivers. On Ubuntu, you can open
>   the Dash to search for programs (just tap the “Super” key — it’s the
>   key with a Windows logo on it on most keyboards). Type “Drivers” to
>   search for the appropriate control panel and click the “Additional
>   Drivers” shortcut. In the Software & Updates window that appears,
>   select the NVIDIA or AMD binary driver if it isn’t already selected
>   and install it.
>
> If you have another Linux distribution, perform a web search to find
>   out how to most easily install the NVIDIA or AMD binary drivers. You
>   can run Minecraft with the default open-source drivers, but the
>   proprietary drivers will improve Minecraft’s performance.
>
> install-nvidia-or-amd-3d-graphics-driver-on-ubuntu-linux
>
> Choose and Install a Java Runtime
>
> Most Linux distributions don’t come with Java, so you’ll need to
>   install it. You have two choices here. There’s open-source version of
>   Java, known as OpenJDK, which is available for easy installation in
>   most Linux distribution’s software repositories. There’s also Oracle’s
>   own Java runtime. The OpenJDK and Oracle Java runtimes are almost
>   identical, but the Oracle Java runtime does contain some closed-source
>   code that might improve graphical performance.
>
> Many people report success with OpenJDK and Minecraft on Linux — it
>   worked for us — but the Minecraft project still recommends using
>   Oracle’s Java runtime. OpenJDK and the official Oracle Java runtime
>   are getting closer together all the time, but you may still want the
>   Oracle one for now.
>
> If you want to try the OpenJDK runtime, this package should be in your
>   Linux distribution’s software repositories. You can just open your
>   desktop’s software management tool and install it. On Ubuntu, click
>   the shopping bag icon on the dock to open the Ubuntu Software Center
>   and search for “OpenJDK.” Install the latest version of the OpenJDK
>   runtime. The process is the same on other Linux distributions — open
>   the software management tool, search for OpenJDK, and install the
>   latest runtime.
>
> install-openjdk-java-on-ubuntu-14.04
>
> If you want Oracle’s Java runtime, you can download it from Java.com.
>   But you probably don’t want to do that.
>
> In the past, Oracle provided easily installable Java packages for
>   Ubuntu and other Linux distributions, but they’ve mostly stopped this
>   in favor of promoting OpenJDK. You’ll probably want to use Oracle Java
>   packages provided by other Linux users for easier installation. For
>   Ubuntu users, there’s a PPA with a Java installer package that will
>   download the Java files from Oracle and install them properly.
>
> To use the PPA, open a terminal (click the Dash icon, search for
>   Terminal, and click the Terminal shortcut) and run the following
>   commands, pressing Enter after each:
>
> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java sudo apt-get update sudo
>   apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
>
> Agree to the prompts and accept Oracle’s Java license agreement when
>   prompted.
>
> install-oracle-java-runtime-for-minecraft-on-ubuntu-14.04
>
> Download and Run Minecraft
>
> Next, download Minecraft. Head to Minecraft’s official download page
>   and click the Minecraft.jar link under Minecraft for Linux/Other.
>
> download-minecraft-for-linux
>
> You can’t just double-click the Minecraft executable because it’s not
>   marked as executable after you download it — you’ll see an error
>   message if you double-click it. First, right-click the Minecraft.jar
>   file and select Properties. Click the Permissions tab and enable the
>   “Allow executing file as program” checkbox.
>
> (This is how you’d do it in the Nautilus file manager used by Ubuntu’s
>   Unity desktop and GNOME, anyway. With other file managers, you should
>   find a similar option in the file’s properties window.)
>
> make-minecraft-jar-launcher-executable-on-ubuntu-linux
>
> Double-click the Minecraft.jar file and the Minecraft Launcher will
>   appear in a window on your desktop — this is the same launcher you’ll
>   see on Windows and Mac. You’ll need to log in with your Minecraft
>   account. If you’ve purchased Minecraft, the launcher will let you play
>   it. If you haven’t purchased the game yet, you can register a new
>   account and play the demo for free.
>
> run-minecraft-launcher-on-ubuntu-linux
>
> Click the Play button and the launcher will handle everything else,
>   automatically downloading Minecraft’s game files and launching it. The
>   launcher will handle updating Minecraft, too.